# Not reading correct value in file handling in C

Tags: c, file, file-handling

My first post :)
I have written a small program in which I read the value from text file and make it print as it is and next print its equivalent binary value
But what I face a problem is the value I print is different from the the one in the file
for eg. I have 23 in my text file and when I try to read it and print the value I am getting 1
anyone has an idea what I am missing or where I am wrong.
I am posting my code here
Thank you in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>





char number_read = 0;
char number = 0;
char number_of_ones = 0;
char remainder_value = 0;
char binary = 0;
char base = 0;



    int main()

{
    FILE *fp;


    fp = fopen ("File.txt","r");

     while(1)
   {
      number_read = fgetc(fp);

      if( feof(fp) )
      { 
         break ;
      }

      printf("\nnumber is=%c", number_read);

      while (number_read>0)
      {
        remainder_value = number_read % 2;
        /*  To count no.of 1s */
        if (remainder_value == 1)
        {
            number_of_ones++;
        }

        binary = binary + remainder_value * base;
        number_read = number_read/2;
        base = base * 10;

      }


    }       
    fprintf("\nINPUT number is = %d\n", number); 
    fprintf("\nIt's in the binary number is = %d\n", binary); 
    fprintf("\nNo.of 1's in the binary number is = %d\n", number_of_ones); 

   fclose(fp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you read a character like '1', you're getting the ASCII value corresponding to that glyph in the character set...not the integer 1.  You have to convert from ASCII to the integer equivalent before using it for arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments passed to `fprintf` function in your case is wrong. Change the part to the following:

```
fprintf(fp,"\nINPUT number is = %d\n", number); 
fprintf(fp,"\nIt's in the binary number is = %d\n", binary); 
fprintf(fp,"\nNo.of 1's in the binary number is = %d\n",number_of_ones);
```

So add `fp` as the first argument to fprintf.

And to obtain the integer value of the character `number_read`, make use of the `atoi` function provided in C. (Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) for reference.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char number_read = 0;
int number = 0;
int number_of_ones = 0;
int remainder_value = 0;
int binary = 0;
int base = 1;

int main(){
FILE *fp = fopen("File.txt", "r");

    while (1){
        number_read = fgetc(fp);

        if (feof(fp)){
            break;
        }
        base = 1;
        number_of_ones = remainder_value = binary = 0;

        printf("\nnumber is=%c\n", number_read);
        number = number_read-48;

        while (number>0){
            remainder_value = number % 2;
            /*  To count no.of 1s */
            if (remainder_value == 1){
                number_of_ones++;
            }

            binary = binary + remainder_value * base;
            number = number/ 2;
            base = base * 10;
            if (number == 1){
                binary = binary + 1 * base;
                number = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\nINPUT number is = %d\n", number_read-48);
        printf("\nIt's in the binary number is = %d\n", binary);
        printf("\nNo.of 1's in the binary number is = %d\n", number_of_ones);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: while you're getting the ASCII value in the character set. Please convert the same to integer equivalent before using it for arithmetic operations.

Comment: @VimalBhaskar: Doesn't s/he do it here: `number = number_read-48;`?

Comment: For most portability this `number = number_read-48;`  should be `number = number_read - '0';`

Comment: i didnt see that at the begining of the code. Yes that should doit. Other better way is he can use atoi conversion. Beacuse it is evident from the OP's query that the file is going to contain only a number. So you can convert the number then and there. Correct me if i am wrong. As even i have come here to get experience. @alk

Comment: @VimalBhaskar: `atoi()` is for a "string", we just have a `char` here. Also for converting "strings" using the members of the `strto*()` family of function is the preferred way to go, as they provide complete error detection, which the `ato*()` functions are missing.

Comment: Thanks for making me understand a new concept today. Will try to incorporate it into my coding and in case if i find any new issues will get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Garryp,

I havent touched the logic of the program, I dont understand the reason why you have kept the base as 0 or all the number variable to char which can be easily acheivable using int variable itself. The only problem you actually had was file operation and please find your updated code. 
Also why is "number" variable used unnecessarily?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int number_read = 0;
char number = 0;
int number_of_ones = 0;
int remainder_value = 0;
int binary = 0;
int base = 1;

int main()

{
FILE *fp,*fp1;
char buff[5];

fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\50022314\\Desktop\\mytest.txt", "r+");
fp1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\50022314\\Desktop\\mytest1.txt", "a+");
while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
{
    number_read = atoi(buff);
    printf("\nnumber is=%d", number_read);
    while (number_read > 0)
    {
        remainder_value = number_read % 2;
        /*  To count no.of 1s */
        if (remainder_value == 1)
        {
            number_of_ones++;
        }

        binary = binary + remainder_value * base;
        number_read = number_read / 2;
        base = base * 10;

    }


    fprintf(fp1, "\nINPUT number is = %d\n", number);
    fprintf(fp1, "\nIt's in the binary number is = %d\n", binary);
    fprintf(fp1, "\nNo.of 1's in the binary number is = %d\n", number_of_ones);
}
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could do with checking the return values from `fopen` (and `fprintf` as well)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thank you for answering to my post 
I have checked what I have done wrongly and Here is  my code which working well
I posted to for future reference for stack follower

still some additional functionality has to be added
I am trying to convert Decimal to binary for numbers from the file
and I have to avoid spaces, blank lines and end of line spaces and then print the number..I am still working on it..anyone gives hint or code will be highly appreciated..thank you all

here is my code  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER 5



char number_read = 0;
char number_of_ones = 0;
char remainder_value = 0;
char binary = 0;
char base = 0;
char buff[BUFFER];



int main()

{
    FILE *fp;                 //file pointer fp
    fp = fopen("File.txt","r+");

  while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
  {
      number_read = atoi(buff);                   //ASCII to integer
      printf("\nnumber is=%d", number_read);
      while (number_read > 0)
       {
         remainder_value = number_read % 2;
         /*  To count no.of 1s */
         if (remainder_value == 1)
           {
            number_of_ones++;
           }

          binary = binary + remainder_value * base;
          number_read = number_read / 2;
          base = base * 10;
       }
         printf("\nNo.of 1's in It's binary representation is = %d\n",number_of_ones); 
         number_of_ones = 0;
  }

   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you all give me Up vote please?? I can not post a question anymore...